# Transform php array into a list of values

Tags: php, arrays

I have a php array of key => value, and I would like to store all the values into a list (like a python list) of values.
I need it cause I have to pass this list of values to a JQuery script.

Basically I have:

```
$var = Array ( [0] => 5 [1] => 7 [2] => 9 [3] => 10 )
```

and I would like to have something like

```
$var = [5, 7, 9, 10];
```

When I call from Jquery my variable:

```
var newvariable = "<?php echo $var ?>";
```

The final goal is to have a Jquery list like:

```
var newvariable = [5,7,9,10];
```

Is this possible in php?

Comment: Check out json_encode(): http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: There's no difference between those two arrays. An array whose keys are sequential integers starting from 0 is the same as an ordinary indexed array.

Comment: Do you mean a string like `$var = "[5, 7, 9, 10]";`

Comment: @Barman no, basically my jQuery var should be: var values = [5, 7, 9, 10];

Comment: $var = implode(',',$var); try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$var = array(5,4,7,5,6,8);
echo json_encode($var);
```

Answer (score 0):

### Check this PHP code :

```
<?php
  $var = array(5, 7, 9, 10);
  $data = json_encode($var) ;
  echo $data ; //[5,7,9,10]
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have a PHP array such as this:

```
$var = array ( 5, 7, 9, 10 );
```

This would print, with `var_dump`:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  int(5)
  [1]=>
  int(7)
  [2]=>
  int(9)
  [3]=>
  int(10)
}
```

PHP has a `list()` language constructor [1]. I don't believe this is what you want though.

Since I'm not sure exactly how this is constructed, I'd suggest looking at the JSON functions [2] PHP has available which might be of help when interacting with jQuery.

Not a definitive answer but I hope it helps.

[1] http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php
[2] http://php.net/manual/en/ref.json.php